# Replace shortcode with output in database?

Tags: shortcode

For example, say I created a shortcode called `[sourcecode]` using the [Shortcode API function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), which is used to share code in posts like so:

```
[sourcecode]
#button {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
[/sourcecode]
```

(And it wraps the code in `<pre><code>` tags, takes care of escaping special characters, etc.)

Then say, after a while I decide to use Markdown (and no longer want to use the `[sourcecode]` shortcode or have its function in my functions.php) or switch to a new blogging platform.

Given the case, I'd like to have all instances of `[sourcecode] .... [/sourcecode]` in all posts replaced with their respective output. For example, if one of the posts has this:

```
[sourcecode]
#button {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
[/sourcecode]
```

It'd be replaced with and saved to database as:

```
<pre><code>#button {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
</code></pre>
```

Similarly, this should happen in all posts that have the `[sourcecode]` shortcode.

Does wordpress have any such regenerate function built-in, or is there a plugin that does what I am after?

Comment: **Plugin:** http://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-cleanup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a function that use [`get_shortcode_regex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) to get the post_content of a post with the shortcode replaced.

Note that any other shoertcode will be untouched

```
function get_replaced_sourcecode_sc( $post ) {
  if ( empty($post) ) global $post;
  if ( empty($post) || ! isset($post->post_content) ) return false;
  $content = $post->post_content;
  if (
    preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches )
    && array_key_exists( 2, $matches ) && in_array( 'sourcecode', $matches[2] )
  ) {
    foreach ( $matches[2] as $i => $sc ) {
      if ( $sc == 'sourcecode' )
        $now = $matches[0][$i];
        $replace = do_shortcode($now);
        $content = str_replace( $now, $replace, $content );
    }
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Now in your `functions.php` you can also add following code:

```
function replaced_sourcecode_sc_all() {

   $already = get_transient('replaced_sourcecode') ? : array();

   $all = get_posts('nopaging=1post_type=post');

    if ( ! empty($all) ) {

      if ( count($all) == count($already) ) {
         error_log('replaced_sourcecode_sc_all already done its work');
         return;
      }

      $done = array();

      foreach ( $all as $one ) {

        if ( in_array($one->ID, $already) ) continue;

        $content = get_replaced_sourcecode_sc( $post );

        $post = array('ID' => $one->ID, 'post_content' => $content);

        $do = wp_update_post( $post );
        if ( $do ) $done[] = $do;

      }

      set_transient('replaced_sourcecode', $done);

    }
}

add_action('shutdown', 'replaced_sourcecode_sc_all');
```

Now, enable WP logging, and then visit your site 2 or 3 times. Check the error log and if you find the string "replaced_sourcecode_sc_all already done its works" you can remove the function (or simply comment out the 'add_action' line).

Comment: So, the first code block goes in my theme's functions.php. Am I supposed to place the second one in a file.php and run it in the browser? Is that what you meant?